# How to verify the uniqueness of a standard matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

I think I have answered this question sufficiently, I just want to know if I am correct, or if I missed anything.

Here is the question:

> Verify the uniqueness of A in Theorem 10. Let *T* : ℝ<sup>n</sup> ⟶ ℝ<sup>m</sup> be a linear transformation such that ***T($\overrightarrow{x}$) = B$\overrightarrow{x}$*** for some *m × n* matrix B. Show that if A is the standard matrix for
>   T, then A = B. [*Hint*: Show that A and B have the same columns.]

Here is Theorem 10:

> Let *T* : ℝ<sup>n</sup> ⟶ ℝ<sup>m</sup> be a linear transformation. Then there exists a unique matrix A such that $$T(\overrightarrow{x}) = A\overrightarrow{x} \text{ for all $\overrightarrow{x}$ in } ℝ^n$$ In fact, A is the m × n matrix whose *j*<sub>th</sub> column is the vector T(e<sub>j</sub>), where e<sub>j</sub> is the *j*<sub>th</sub> column of the identity matrix in ℝ<sup>n</sup>: $$A=[T(\overrightarrow{e_1})\text{ . . . }T(\overrightarrow{e_n})]$$

Here is my answer:

> A = [ T<sub>A</sub>($\overrightarrow{e_1}$) . . . T<sub>A</sub>($\overrightarrow{e_n}$) ]
>
> B = [ T<sub>B</sub>($\overrightarrow{e_1}$) . . . T<sub>B</sub>($\overrightarrow{e_n}$) ]
>
> *assuming* A$\overrightarrow{x}$ = T = B$\overrightarrow{x}$
>
> A$\overrightarrow{x}$ = B$\overrightarrow{x}$
>
> A$\overrightarrow{x}$ - B$\overrightarrow{x} = \overrightarrow{0}$
>
> ( [ T<sub>A</sub>($\overrightarrow{e_1}$) . . . T<sub>A</sub>($\overrightarrow{e_n}$) ] - [ T<sub>B</sub>($\overrightarrow{e_1}$) . . . T<sub>B</sub>($\overrightarrow{e_n}$) ] )$\overrightarrow{x}$ = $\overrightarrow{0}$
>
> [ T<sub>A</sub>($\overrightarrow{e_1}$) - T<sub>B</sub>($\overrightarrow{e_1}$) . . . T<sub>A</sub>($\overrightarrow{e_n}$) - T<sub>B</sub>($\overrightarrow{e_n}$) ]$\overrightarrow{x}$ = $\overrightarrow{0}$
>
> *Here is where I feel like I might be jumping to conclusions without proper reasoning*
>
> [ $\overrightarrow{0_1}$ . . . $\overrightarrow{0_n}$ ]$\overrightarrow{x}$ = $\overrightarrow{0}$ $\forall$ $\overrightarrow{x}$ $\in$ ℝ<sup>n</sup>; $\overrightarrow{x}$≠$\overrightarrow{0}$
>
> ∴ T<sub>A</sub>($\overrightarrow{e_j}$) = T<sub>B</sub>($\overrightarrow{e_j}$)
>
> A = B

This is my first attempt at stating any kind of proof, and any help revising it would be much appreciated.

```
-Edit-
```

Using Eric Wofsey's reasoning that

> Ax=Bx  for any vector x

then can I just say that

> A$\overrightarrow{e_j}$ = B$\overrightarrow{e_j}$
>
> $\overrightarrow{A_j}$ = $\overrightarrow{B_j}$
>
> A = B

is it really this simple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The step you are concerned about is indeed incorrect.  Basically, your argument is that $(A-B)x=0$ for any vector $x$, and the zero matrix also satisfies $0_{m\times n}x=0$ for any vector $x$, therefore $A-B=0_{m\times n}$.  But this logic is wrong: how do you know there can't be two *different* matrices which, when multiplied by any vector, give $0$?

Instead, you're going to need to use the fact that $Ax=Bx$ for *any* vector $x$.  This means you can choose $x$ to be any specific vector you want.  Can you think of any specific choice of $x$ for which the equation $Ax=Bx$ would tell you some useful information about the entries of $A$ and $B$?

Comment: $\overrightarrow{x}$ = $\overrightarrow{e_j}$?

Comment: Yep, that works.